# How do I remove matplotlib text output in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, jupyter-notebook

I am currently writing an undergraduate senior thesis using jupyter notebook. When I convert my notebook to pdf using latex, it keeps these function calls in the form of text(I am not sure what to call them).

For example, if I attempt to create a pie chart with this code:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
df['fraud'].value_counts().plot.pie(autopct='%1.3f%%',explode=[0,0.1])
plt.show
```

The pie chart outputs correctly, but it also adds this line of text:

**<function matplotlib.pyplot.show(close=None, block=None)>**

Is there a way to only output the chart?

Comment: generally, to suppress any output in jupyter notebook (except for those from  `print`), just add `; ` after your last command in the cell :-).

Comment: @QuangHoang that is extremely useful as well thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `plt.show` to `plt.show()`.